# Text based game using an input in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried finding tutorials and anything I could to make a text based game that uses an input but tutorials only show how to do it with buttons.

What I want to happen is if you say "start game" then it changes the `innerHTML` and says "You are in the woods", then if you type "look around" in the input, the `innerHTML` says "there is only trees". But I want to make it so the "look around" only works if you say "start game".

```
var stn_inp = document.getElementById("stn_inp");
var displayInp = document.getElementById("displayInput");
var nar = document.getElementById("narriator");

function showInp() {
        var inp = stn_inp.value;
        displayInp.innerHTML = inp;

        if (inp == "start game") {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                nar.innerHTML = "Let's begin.";
            }, 500)

            window.setTimeout(function () {
                nar.innerHTML = "You are in the woods.";
            },1500)

            if (inp == "look around") {
                nar.innerHTML = "there is only trees";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a variable taht contains if the ame is started or not then set it when you type "start game" and check if the game has started when you type something else:

```
var stn_inp = document.getElementById("stn_inp");
var displayInp = document.getElementById("displayInput");
var nar = document.getElementById("narriator");
var gameStarted = false;

function showInp() {
        var inp = stn_inp.value;
        displayInp.innerHTML = inp;

        if (inp == "start game") {
            gameStarted = true;
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                nar.innerHTML = "Let's begin.";
            }, 500);

            window.setTimeout(function () {
                nar.innerHTML = "You are in the woods.";
            }, 1500);
        }

        if(gameStarted){
            if (inp == "look around") {
                nar.innerHTML = "there is only trees";
            }
        }else{
            nar.innerHTML = "you haven't started the game yet.";
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I do have one question though, how to make it work if I wanna have heaps of different ending and options? Should I make a tons of different variables that equal false or is there a better way of doing?

Comment: yes, you can make tons of boolean variable but also use something like a happiness variable and if it is less than for example 5, there is a 'sad' ending otherwise an 'happy' ending.